# When i write the script it shows ReferenceError: theWidth is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var theImage = $('ul li img');
  var theWidth = theImage.width();
  //wrap into mother div
  $('ul').wrap('<div class="gallery-slide" />');
  //assign height width and overflow hidden to gallery-slide
  $('.gallery-slide').css({
    width: function() {
      return theWidth;
    },
    height: function() {
      return theImage.height();
    },
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  });
  //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul
  var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
  $('ul').css({
    width: function() {
      return totalWidth;
    }
  });
});

$('ul li img').each(function(intIndex) {
  $(this).nextAll('a').bind("click", function() {

    if ($(this).is(".next")) {
      $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
        "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * theWidth)
      }, 1000);
    } else if ($(this).is(".previous")) {
      $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
        "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * theWidth)
      }, 1000);
    } else if ($(this).is(".startover")) {
      $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
        "margin-left": (0)
      }, 1000);
    }
  }); //close .bind()
}); //close .each()
```

The above is my code which throws error `theWidth` is not defined.

Comment: Please align the code properly

Answer (score 1):

> JavaScript has [`function-level` scope](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/javascript/javascript-block-scope/)(before `ECMAScript 6`), if a variable declared inside some block of code enclosed by `curly braces` is only visible within that block of code, and that variable is not visible outside of that particular block of code.

`theWidth` is defined under the scope of `$(window).load` which is `undefined` out of the scope of the `.load` handler.

Wrap all of your code in the `load` handler.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var theImage = $('ul li img');
  var theWidth = theImage.width();
  //wrap into mother div
  $('ul').wrap('<div class="gallery-slide" />');
  //assign height width and overflow hidden to gallery-slide
  $('.gallery-slide').css({
    width: function() {
      return theWidth;
    },
    height: function() {
      return theImage.height();
    },
    position: 'relative',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  });
  //get total of image sizes and set as width for ul
  var totalWidth = theImage.length * theWidth;
  $('ul').css({
    width: function() {
      return totalWidth;
    }
  });
  $('ul li img').each(function(intIndex) {
    $(this).nextAll('a').bind("click", function() {

      if ($(this).is(".next")) {
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
          "margin-left": (-(intIndex + 1) * theWidth)
        }, 1000);
      } else if ($(this).is(".previous")) {
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
          "margin-left": (-(intIndex - 1) * theWidth)
        }, 1000);
      } else if ($(this).is(".startover")) {
        $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').animate({
          "margin-left": (0)
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Javascript does **not** have block-level scope...which is actually something the article you link to explains. Block-level scope would mean **any** block has its own scope (including if statements, loops, etc.). Javascript does not have this. It has **function** level scope. With newer standards JS has the ability to do block-level scope using the `let` keyword instead of `var`, but that is not fully implemented and definitely not part of this example/problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you declare `theWidth` inside one function, then try to use it inside a separate function outside of that one's scope.

This is how scope works in javascript:

```
var foo = 'bar';

function f() {
    console.log(foo); // works!
}
```

That works because function `f` is inside the scope where `foo` is declared...so you can use it.

```
function e() {
    var foo = 'bar';
}

function f() {
    console.log(foo); // doesn't work!
}
```

That doesn't work. var `foo` was declared inside the scope of `e`, and `f` is not inside the scope of `e`, so foo will not be available to it.

```
function e() {
    var foo = 'bar';

    function f() {
        console.log(foo); // works again!
    }
}
```

Now it works again, because `f` is inside the scope of `e` where `foo` is declared.

Hopefully that will help demonstrate how scope works.